# How to take the id value of dynamic data when using draggable in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have two divs parents where I am displaying some dynamic data from the database. The data are being displayed inside children divs, so, when dragging from one div to the other I would like to take the id of that item as well. For now, I just want to be able to print it in Javascript using the alert function.

**Javascript functions:**

```
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

**Html divs with PHP data:**

```
 <fieldset id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend style="color:cadetblue; border:white; width:auto; font:bold">Vacant parking spots</legend>
    <?php foreach ($sql_get_vacant_spots_results_ as $row) { ?>
        <div id="free_spots_div" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
            <labled style="color: white; font:bold; font-size:large;"><?php echo ' Spot: ' . $row['spot_no'] . ' Gate: ' . $row['parking_gate_id'] ?></label>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</fieldset>

 <fieldset id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend style="color:cadetblue; border:white; width:auto; font:bold">Current parking spots of the customer</legend>
    <?php foreach ($arr_users as $user) { ?>
        <div id="customers_spot_div" draggable="true" width="88" height="31">
            <labled style="color: white; font:bold; font-size:large;"><?php echo ' Spot: ' . $user['spot_id'] . ' Gate: ' .  $user['gate_id'] ?></label>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Your `id` are in a loop and thus not unique. Therefore you will probably always get the first occurance with `getElementById`. Be aware to give elements unique `id`. You could just add the *rownumber* or use *parking_gate_id* for instance.

Comment: @Lain to the div id?

Comment: Every `id` should be unique, regardless of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `for-loop` will repeat the elements `id`. `id` should be unique in the whole document. Also your `div` current have two attributes `id`:

```
<div id="free_spots_div" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
```

[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will just select the first ocurrance of a matching element.

Here is a small sample with additional `console.log()`.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ;console.log('drag', ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ;console.log('drop', ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend style="color:cadetblue; border:white; width:auto; font:bold">Vacant parking spots</legend>
    
    <!-- id are to be unique -->
    <div id="free_spots_div1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="88" height="31">
        <labled style="font:bold; font-size:large;">parking_gate_id1</label>
    </div>

    <!-- id are to be unique -->
    <div id="free_spots_div2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="88" height="31">
        <labled style="font:bold; font-size:large;">parking_gate_id2</label>
    </div>

    <!-- id are to be unique -->
    <div id="free_spots_div3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="88" height="31">
        <labled style="font:bold; font-size:large;">parking_gate_id3</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>

 <fieldset id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend style="color:cadetblue; border:white; width:auto; font:bold">Current parking spots of the customer</legend>
    <div id="customers_spot_div" draggable="true" width="88" height="31">
        <labled style="font:bold; font-size:large;">gate_id</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I got the point. however, now that I think I have a bigger issue. None of the elements has a unique id because when I am fetching from the database I am fetching from a relational table which doesn't have an auto-increment id. So I am distinguishing based on 3 fields.

Comment: Use all three fields as a key, add a *counter* in the loop or use *rownumber* in your database and add it to the `id`.

Comment: How can I atually print those id with Alert because I tried with console.log and it doesn't print anything, strange. I am using a counter now and I want to print but don't see anything

Comment: Oh, I did not touch *php* for twenty years.. but according to your example it should be something like `<div id="free_spots_div<?php echo $counter; ?>"` or `<div id="free_spots_div<?=$counter;?>"`. For the `alert` you can add `alert(ev.target.id)` to `drag()`. Yet be aware that alerting cancels dragging. Lastly make sure to only have one `id` attribute on your element, unlike in your example.

Comment: yea fixed the problem already thanks. What I am really trying to implement is POST as soon as an item is dropped to the opposite side. So I think to pass the entire array as ID if possible. You think is doable?

Comment: Certainly is. However, if you have different questions you should create new questions and not mix them into each other. And do not forget to post the structure if you need advice on the structure itself. In the end the DOM does not care what your `id` represents, are long as it is unique. Also you can add the whole **row** in a data-attribute as well and parse it on need.